# How to delete two linked rows from MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, delphi, foreign-keys

Can somebody show my how to delete two linked rows?

I use Delphi 2007 and MySQL.

I have a database with two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Picture`.`Picture` (
  `ID` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IMG` LONGBLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `FirstName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `PICID` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_contacts_1` (`PICID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_contacts_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PICID`) REFERENCES `picture` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

In my Delphi Application I have <kbd>Delete</kbd> button. When I find some contact on my DBGrid and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> button I can delete only contact from table `contacts`, I also want to delete contact picture.

I want to delete row from table `contacts` and row from table `Picture`. Table `Picture` is linked to table `contacts` with `foreign key`.

Comment: Append `ON DELETE CASCADE` after the foreign key constraint. This will solve your problem, whether you are using Delphi or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use FK with `ON DELETE CASCADE` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

When you delete a row from the master table `Picture` SQL engine cascades to detail table and deletes there too.

Comment: @nalply are you sure it would definitely cascade? any version of mySQL with any table backend ? i wrote "should cascade" with intention.

Comment: It's important that the engine is InnoDB. I have a project which uses exactly this. The Op has `ENGINE = InnoDB`, so don't worry.